# Virtual Directories not working in ColdFusion Builder 2016

Tags: apache, http, coldfusion, tomcat8, coldfusionbuilder

I'm trying to set up virtual directories through the built-in Apache Tomcat 8 server using the ColdFusion Builder 2016 interface, however to my surprise this simply does not work, yet according to the documentation it should.

The only thing that I've modified was the **web root** directly in the `server.xml` file.

That said the website runs correctly, except when trying to reference a resource from a virtual directory which simply returns `HTTP Status 404`.

### Web Structure

[image: Web Structure]

### ColdFusion Builder Interface

The process when using the interface is as simple as:

1. Creating a virtual host;

[image: ColdFusion Builder 2016 - Virtual Host Settings]

2. Clicking the "Virtual Directory" button and setting up the directories; and

[image]

3. Applying the changes and restart the local server.

---

Ultimately this should allow me to navigate to the files (CSS, JS, Images) directly through the web browser.

Could I be missing a specific setting in a configuration file due to manually changing the web root? If not what am I missing?